# Flutter easy_web_view not working, how fix?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
import 'package:easy_web_view/easy_web_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: EasyWebView(
          src: "https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics",
          onLoaded: () {
            print('');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Not running with sound null safety.*
*Error:*

Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51163/5mo8ELl135w=/ws

Error: Unexpected null value.

```
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51134/dart_sdk.js:5386:11)
at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:51134/dart_sdk.js:5721:30)
```

...

```
at http://localhost:51134/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:654:14
at internalCallback (http://localhost:51134/dart_sdk.js:27601:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use it as stated [here](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) it is working

isHtml: false, is not available in version 1.6.0
Check the Install tab on that page on how to add it to your project.
I used the standard app when creating a new one and added easywebview to test it.
I want it to work for web and windows/macos too, maybe someone can join this thread on how to do that.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_web_view/easy_web_view.dart';
//import 'package:webview_windows/webview_windows.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String src = 'https://flutter.dev';
  bool _isHtml = false;
  bool _isMarkdown = false;
  bool _useWidgets = false;
  bool _editing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Easy Web View'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(_editing ? Icons.close : Icons.settings),
              onPressed: () {
                if (mounted)
                  setState(() {
                    _editing = !_editing;
                  });
              },
            );
          }),
        ],
      ),
      body: _editing
          ? SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      )
          : EasyWebView(
        src: src,
        //isHtml: false,
        isMarkdown: false,
        convertToWidgets: false,
        // width: 100,
        // height: 100,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, it is not working flutter web. do you know a solution?

Comment: No sorry, I changed to https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter